# Reacting to misuse of [react]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

I just saw the [react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react) tag for PHP event library. The tag explicitly says that "For the JavaScript library for building interactive components, use the [reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs) tag". Still, most of the questions asked under this tag is related to [reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs) and not to the react php library.

It building confusion for users which searching react php library related questions.

- What could be the solution?
- Are similar cases handled before?
- As there are lot of questions, Is retagging the only option?

Comment: 130 question is not much, so simply retagging would work. I already did the ones that had both tags ...

Comment: I guess the only way to solve it is destroying [react] and retagging everything. The php-questions to [tag:reactphp], the others to their already existing proper tags.

Comment: I fixed most questions with [`[react] -[javascript]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react+-javascript). 4 question need to be disambiguated.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Keeping in mind that "nobody reads", and there's no chance of changing this anytime this millenium, trying to reserve [react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react) for any one of the different frameworks named react, be it the PHP or the JavaScript one, is doomed to fail.

The only sustainable solution is burning it and re-tagging all questions appropriately, the PHP ones to the new [reactphp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactphp), the others to the longer-established tags.

Update: Finished cleaning up the last questions a good two hours ago.
And thanks for those who chipped in with their own edits.

[image: Trogdor]

Comment: reactphp tag, That is what I am thinking yesterday is better. As react js is more popular then It would be more hard to keep future reactjs question only on reactjs tag and not on react tag. Just hope, people are enough wise not to use reactphp tag for react js questions.

Comment: One more thing, reactphp tag's details is same as react tag. Is it time to change that details + excerpt ?

Comment: @kuldeep.kamboj Did so. Anyway, as I just retagged and generally cleaned up the last questions, it will be gone soon enough.

Comment: [One very last](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29424470/4099598). We'll have to wait another UTC day before the tag is Roomba'd.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: I hate when those come in at the last second before the cleanup task does its magic. Luckily, this time there was none.