# Question cleanup tagged with [html] + [select]

Tags: discussion, tags, clean-up

As most of you are already aware, [select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select)'s [wiki](//stackoverflow.com/tags/select/info) clearly mentions its usage not to be linked with the [HTML's `select` element](http://devdocs.io/html/element/select):

> ### In HTML
>
> `<select>` is also an HTML user interface element for choosing one or
>   more option(s) from a finite collection of elements. **Do not use this
>   tag for this purpose, use [html-select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-select) instead.**

Yet, there are about 1.2k questions tagged with simple select. Can we clean up the questions tagged as [html+select](//stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select+html)?

Comment: That's a lot of questions..

Comment: Similar problem as I raised for other tag (React) http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289091/reacting-to-misuse-of-react . But it have 10x questions to resolve than react tag.

Comment: "Can we clean up the questions tagged as html+select?" Not automatically that's for sure.

Comment: Is it really worth it?

Comment: @DavidGrinberg, If there is an automated way to do it, yes.

Comment: @JonasCz How could there be an automated way to tell if you are talking about HTML select vs SQL select? Don't forget it needs to be accurate - and you have to take into account single-tag questions. There is currently no way, which is why I say this really isnt worth it.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg, If they are tagged [html] + [select] It's quite likely that they should be tagged with [html-select]. Single tag questions could be cleaned up after. (I doubt that there are many).